How to stop ESP IDF monitor terminal in Visual Studio Code
The output of an ESP-IDF firmware is shown in a terminal window of Visual Studio Code under Ubuntu 24.04:

when there is a fatal error that quickly reboot the system, the terminal is full in few seconds and the old content is overwritten by the new one.
You cannot focus on some lines to read what happens because it automatically scrolls down when the terminal buffer is full. For the same reason you can't easily copy and paste the content elsewhere.
I didn't find a way to stop the terminal (without killing it).
Using PlatformIO, for example, I can use CTRL+C that closes the serial connection leaving the content in the terminal for inspection.
I'm not able to do the same with the ESP-IDF Monitor terminal, though.

outside vscode, you can use ctrl+t ctrl+x, but not sure if the VS Code extension mirrors this functionality or even supports interrupting/"exiting" the monitor. https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/issues/8508#issuecomment-1059932483

Not an answer, but related to your problem: In development, I always set the CONFIG_ESP_SYSTEM_PANIC_REBOOT_DELAY_SECONDS menuconfig option to 5 seconds or so, so that the ESP waits 5 seconds before rebooting when a fatal error occurs, so that I have time to quite the terminal/read the logs/backtrace

@Arco this is a very useful hint, indeed!

When the terminal monitor comes up, it says what shortcuts can be used for this purpose: (Quit: Ctrl+] | Menu: Ctrl+T | Help: Ctrl+T followed by Ctrl+H ---)1
Edit:
use Ctrl+T, then X to exit, if Ctrl+] doesn't work (thanks to @JimmyB).
Complete set of IDF Monitor shortcuts

In my installation Ctrl+] increase the zoom of the IDE, Ctrl+T+H shows the menu, but none of the commands works. And none of the listed command allows to pause or detach/close the port. I didn't change the default settings

But these shortcuts are specific to IDF Monitor and should work if entered into the terminal. Anyway, the complete set of IDF Monitor shortcuts is given in this link: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/stable/esp32/api-guides/tools/idf-monitor.html

@Mark Try Ctrl+T, then X.

@JimmyB yeah, that combination works. Thanks! If you provide such an answer I'll accept it
